# How to plot id and time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a csv file and I load the data in `df`.

```
time     d          e         f      id
 1 -0.3813535 -0.3766915 1.2365178    a
 2 -0.5192448 -0.8325136 0.7229763    a
 3  0.3292604 -0.3832252 1.2250516    b
 4  0.5438868 -1.1085977 1.3113659    b
 5 -0.6883436 -1.9918862 0.5804269    a
 6  0.7651908 -0.6465595 1.1116675    b
 7  0.8359222 -0.1933391 2.3156759    a
 8  1.5074557 -0.1650911 2.3737362    b
 9  0.7095554  2.2623272 3.0409351    a
10  0.7137618  2.7033626 2.5880434    b
```

Actually I want to take 2 plots for `id` a and b.

What I have until now are plot for time

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape)
   df <- melt(df ,  id = 'time')

   ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(series ~ .)
```

Update data format:

```
 time     d             id
 1 -0.3813535     a
 2 -0.5192448     a
 3  0.3292604     b
 4  0.5438868     b
 5 -0.6883436     a
 6  0.7651908     b
 7  0.8359222     a
 8  1.5074557     b
 9  0.7095554     a
10  0.7137618     b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question it is not clear how plot should look but there is at least two possible ways.

At the begging melt your data (used library `reshape2`) and use columns `time` and `id` as `id.vars=`.

```
library(reshape2)
df.long <- melt(df ,  id.vars = c("time","id"))
head(df.long)
  time id variable      value
1    1  a        d -0.3813535
2    2  a        d -0.5192448
3    3  b        d  0.3292604
4    4  b        d  0.5438868
5    5  a        d -0.6883436
6    6  b        d  0.7651908
```

First variant - use `variable` to get different colors of line and then `id` in facetting.

```
ggplot(df.long,aes(time,value,color=variable))+geom_line()+
         facet_grid(id~.)
```

[image]

Second variant - if all lines should be in separate facets, then use both `variable` and `id` in facetting.

```
ggplot(df.long,aes(time,value))+geom_line()+
      facet_grid(variable~id)
```

[image]

### UPDATE - solution with new data

If the data are already in long format (no need to melt data) than just use `facet_grid(id~.)` and `group=id` to have lines in separate facets.

```
ggplot(df,aes(time,d,group=id))+geom_line()+facet_grid(id~.)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that with 132 plots you will achieve something good. Maybe add scales="free_y" to have different y axis for each facet.

Comment: Something like that ggplot(df,aes(time,d,group=id))+geom_line()+facet_grid(id~.), scales="free_y")?

Comment: ggplot(df,aes(time,d,group=id))+geom_line()+facet_grid(id~., scales="free_y") You had extra ")" after id~.)

Comment: Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_upviewport, as.integer(n)) : 
  cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)